# My application crashes in production environment but work fine at development environment

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

I have a problem in production environment.
My application start and restart after about 4 minutes.
My application work fine in development environment and only in production environment its behavior it.
Log of `jvm` when it crashes as following:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaabca5e20, pid=29682, tid=46914145687872
#
# JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J  com.tosan.sipa.security.jceadapter.JCESMAdapter.d([B[B)[B
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00002aaabef69800):  JavaThread "PooledThread-98-running" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=417, stack(0x00002aab0ced1000,0x00002aab0cfd2000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000000b05bccf8

Registers:
RAX=0x00000007b05bcd10, RBX=0x00000000b05bcce6, RCX=0x0000000000000002, RDX=0x0000000000000008
RSP=0x00002aab0cfcf580, RBP=0x000000000000000a, RSI=0x0000000000000007, RDI=0x0000000000000001
R8 =0x0000000000000053, R9 =0x0000000000000009, R10=0x0000000000000002, R11=0x0000000000000007
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000007b0000510, R14=0x0000000000000010, R15=0x00002aaabef69800
RIP=0x00002aaaabca5e20, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00002aab0cfcf580)
0x00002aab0cfcf580:   0000000700000007 00000007b05bccf0
0x00002aab0cfcf590:   00000006fe19e4ac 00002aab0cfcf5f0
0x00002aab0cfcf5a0:   00000006fe1a3710 00000006ff05fcb8

Instructions: (pc=0x00002aaaabca5e20)
0x00002aaaabca5e00:   48 8b 34 24 4c 63 d1 47 0f be 4c 15 10 45 85 c9
0x00002aaaabca5e10:   0f 8c 4f 01 00 00 47 0f b6 4c 15 10 41 83 e1 0f
0x00002aaaabca5e20:   42 0f be 54 13 10 85 d2 0f 8c 47 01 00 00 42 0f
0x00002aaaabca5e30:   b6 54 13 10 83 e2 0f 8b f9 83 e7 01 85 c9 0f 8c 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000007b05bcd10 is an oop
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 12
RBX=0x00000000b05bcce6 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000008 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00002aab0cfcf580 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00002aaabef69800
RBP=0x000000000000000a is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000053 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000009 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000007 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000007b0000510 is an oop
[B 
 - klass: {type array byte}
 - length: 7
R14=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R15=0x00002aaabef69800 is a thread


Stack: [0x00002aab0ced1000,0x00002aab0cfd2000],  sp=0x00002aab0cfcf580,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J  com.tosan.sipa.security.jceadapter.JCESMAdapter.d([B[B)[B


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00002aab1c029800 JavaThread "InactivityMonitor Async Task: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@47553709" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19197, stack(0x00002aab27979000,0x00002aab27a7a000)]
  0x00002aaabcb7b800 JavaThread "PooledThread-463-running" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=18059, stack(0x00002aab27d7d000,0x00002aab27e7e000)]

7f76d000-7f770000 ---p 7f76d000 00:00 0 
7f770000-7f86e000 rwxp 7f770000 00:00 0 
7f86e000-7f871000 ---p 7f86e000 00:00 0 
7f871000-7f96f000 rwxp 7f871000 00:00 0 
7f96f000-7f972000 ---p 7f96f000 00:00 0 
744800000-324481c000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135356                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3244a1b000-3244a1c000 r-xp 0001b000 68:03 50135356                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3244a1c000-3244a1d000 rwxp 0001c000 68:03 50135356                       /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3244c00000-3244d4e000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135357                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3244d4e000-3244f4d000 ---p 0014e000 68:03 50135357                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3244f4d000-3244f51000 r-xp 0014d000 68:03 50135357                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3244f51000-3244f52000 rwxp 00151000 68:03 50135357                       /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3244f52000-3244f57000 rwxp 3244f52000 00:00 0 
3245000000-3245082000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135365                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3245082000-3245281000 ---p 00082000 68:03 50135365                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3245281000-3245282000 r-xp 00081000 68:03 50135365                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3245282000-3245283000 rwxp 00082000 68:03 50135365                       /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3245400000-3245402000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135359                       /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3245402000-3245602000 ---p 00002000 68:03 50135359                       /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3245602000-3245603000 r-xp 00002000 68:03 50135359                       /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3245603000-3245604000 rwxp 00003000 68:03 50135359                       /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3245800000-3245816000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135360                       /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3245816000-3245a15000 ---p 00016000 68:03 50135360                       /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3245a15000-3245a16000 r-xp 00015000 68:03 50135360                       /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3245a16000-3245a17000 rwxp 00016000 68:03 50135360                       /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3245a17000-3245a1b000 rwxp 3245a17000 00:00 0 
3246000000-3246007000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135361                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3246007000-3246207000 ---p 00007000 68:03 50135361                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3246207000-3246208000 r-xp 00007000 68:03 50135361                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3246208000-3246209000 rwxp 00008000 68:03 50135361                       /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3249400000-3249415000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135370                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3249415000-3249614000 ---p 00015000 68:03 50135370                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3249614000-3249615000 r-xp 00014000 68:03 50135370                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3249615000-3249616000 rwxp 00015000 68:03 50135370                       /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3249616000-3249618000 rwxp 3249616000 00:00 0 
324a800000-324a811000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135372                       /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
324a811000-324aa11000 ---p 00011000 68:03 50135372                       /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
324aa11000-324aa12000 r-xp 00011000 68:03 50135372                       /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
324aa12000-324aa13000 rwxp 00012000 68:03 50135372                       /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
324aa13000-324aa15000 rwxp 324aa13000 00:00 0 
2aaaaaaab000-2aaaaaaad000 r-xs 00009000 68:03 44695565                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/12392f1f-f3d1-4311-a0b8-b4e193c19c01.922.5.0.68.jar
2aaaaaaad000-2aaaaaaae000 r-xs 00000000 68:03 44695586                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/3fa946bd-26ea-4f57-a5d4-78a9ae348175.922.5.0.68.jar
2aaaaaaae000-2aaaaaab0000 r-xs 00008000 68:03 44695581                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/2f78f9e3-de6d-442a-bc37-a49a5ed054f9.922.5.0.68.jar
aaaaabf000-2aaaaaac0000 r-xs 00004000 68:03 42012270                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/spring-batch-test-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
2aaaaaac1000-2aaaaaace000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304397                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
2aaaaaace000-2aaaaabcd000 ---p 0000d000 68:03 42304397                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
2aaaaabcd000-2aaaaabd0000 rwxp 0000c000 68:03 42304397                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
2aaaaabd0000-2aaaaabf9000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304409                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaaabf9000-2aaaaacf8000 ---p 00029000 68:03 42304409                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaaacf8000-2aaaaacff000 rwxp 00028000 68:03 42304409                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaaacff000-2aaaaad00000 r-xp 2aaaaacff000 00:00 0 
2aaaaad00000-2aaaaad01000 rwxp 2aaaaad00000 00:00 0 
2aaaaad01000-2aaaaad0a000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304369                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libinstrument.so
2aaaaad0a000-2aaaaae09000 ---p 00009000 68:03 42304369                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libinstrument.so
2aaaaae09000-2aaaaae0b000 rwxp 00008000 68:03 42304369                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libinstrument.so
2aaaaae0b000-2aaaaae13000 rwxs 00000000 68:03 53772310                   /tmp/hsperfdata_root/29682
2aaaaae13000-2aaaaae1a000 r-xs 00031000 68:03 44695592                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/526c8739-952f-4c2f-b7fe-59362ac5c475.922.5.0.68.jar
2aaaaae1a000-2aaaaae1c000 r-xs 00007000 68:03 44695594                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/54c08ee1-0fad-4b53-a7c9-0264492dd22a.922.5.0.68.jar
2aaaaae1c000-2aaaaae1d000 r-xs 00003000 68:03 44695597                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/66e14507-4501-475f-8656-7bb4022e08cb.922.5.0.68.jar
2aaaaae1d000-2aaaaae1f000 r-xs 00008000 68:03 44695576                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/29a30217-d53a-4d93-a87b-c57be9af9a65.922.5.0.68.jar
2aaaaae20000-2aaaaae2a000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135065                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaaae2a000-2aaaab029000 ---p 0000a000 68:03 50135065                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaab029000-2aaaab02a000 r-xp 00009000 68:03 50135065                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaab02a000-2aaaab02b000 rwxp 0000a000 68:03 50135065                   /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaab02b000-2aaaab039000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304378                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
2aaaab039000-2aaaab13b000 ---p 0000e000 68:03 42304378                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
2aaaab13b000-2aaaab13e000 rwxp 00010000 68:03 42304378                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
2aaaab13e000-2aaaabcaf000 rwxp 2aaaab13e000 00:00 0 
2aaaaefa1000-2aaaaefa8000 rwxp 2aaaaefa1000 00:00 0 
2aaaaefa8000-2aaaaf140000 r-xs 03029000 68:03 42304593                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/rt.jar
2aaaaf140000-2aaaaff82000 rwxp 2aaaaf140000 00:00 0 
aaaafffe000-2aaab0000000 r-xs 00000000 68:03 44695578                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/2a037d5e-de63-4110-aaf2-5ddd0655ae7a.922.5.0.68.jar
2aaab0000000-2aaab3ffe000 rwxp 2aaab0000000 00:00 0 
2aaab3ffe000-2aaab4000000 ---p 2aaab3ffe000 00:00 0 
2aaab4000000-2aaab4505000 rwxp 2aaab4000000 00:00 0 
2aaab4505000-2aaab7ad5000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 40930801                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
2aaab7ad5000-2aaab7ad8000 r-xs 0000d000 68:03 44695605                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/7389220d-8a42-48a7-a3bb-4bda5bc2dc4d.922.5.0.68.jar
b7afb000-2aaab7afe000 r-xs 00009000 68:03 44695601                   /home/sipa/release/switch/sipa.lib/7047da77-1c21-437c-855b-99d588bab702.922.5.0.68.jar
ab7c03000-2aaab7c0a000 r-xs 0003c000 68:03 42012201                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/mail.jar
aaab7d18000-2aaab7d1d000 r-xs 0003c000 68:03 42012228                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/ehcache-1.5.0.jar
2aaab7d1d000-2aaab7d1f000 r-xs 0000e000 68:03 42012229                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/activation-1.1.jar
2aaab7d1f000-2aaab7d2b000 r-xs 0007c000 68:03 42012230                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7d2b000-2aaab7d30000 r-xs 00040000 68:03 42012231                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar
2aaab7d30000-2aaab7d32000 r-xs 00000000 68:03 42012232                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/aopalliance.jar
2aaab7d32000-2aaab7d41000 r-xs 0016d000 68:03 42012234                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/ojdbc14.jar
2aaab7d41000-2aaab7d42000 r-xs 00008000 68:03 42012235                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/commons-cli.jar
2aaab7d42000-2aaab7d4b000 r-xs 00048000 68:03 42012236                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/backport-util-concurrent.jar
2aaab7d4b000-2aaab7d5e000 r-xs 000c4000 68:03 42012237                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.jar
2aaab7d5e000-2aaab7d6e000 r-xs 0007c000 68:03 42012238                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/joda-time-2.1.jar
2aaab7d6e000-2aaab7d73000 r-xs 00048000 68:03 42012239                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
2aaab7d73000-2aaab7d7b000 r-xs 0004a000 68:03 42012240                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7d7b000-2aaab7d80000 r-xs 00029000 68:03 42012241                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7d80000-2aaab7d83000 r-xs 00018000 68:03 42012242                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/XmlSchema-1.0.1.jar
2aaab7d83000-2aaab7d8b000 r-xs 0008a000 68:03 42012243                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
2aaab7d8b000-2aaab7d8d000 r-xs 00003000 68:03 42012244                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar
2aaab7d8d000-2aaab7d9c000 r-xs 00126000 68:03 42012245                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/je-3.3.82.jar
2aaab7d9c000-2aaab7d9e000 r-xs 00006000 68:03 42012246                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/activemq-jaas-5.5.0.jar
2aaab7d9e000-2aaab7da5000 r-xs 0005d000 68:03 42012247                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/mx4j.jar
2aaab7da5000-2aaab7dac000 r-xs 0006a000 68:03 42012250                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/quartz-all-1.8.4.jar
2aaab7dac000-2aaab7dad000 r-xs 00001000 68:03 42012251                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7dad000-2aaab7db1000 r-xs 00027000 68:03 42012252                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7db1000-2aaab7db5000 r-xs 00027000 68:03 42012253                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/jmxremote.jar
2aaab7db5000-2aaab7dc9000 r-xs 00174000 68:03 42012254                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/axis-1.2.1.jar
2aaab7dc9000-2aaab7dca000 r-xs 0000c000 68:03 42012255                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7dca000-2aaab7dd5000 r-xs 0006f000 68:03 42012256                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/mx4j-tools.jar
2aaab7dd5000-2aaab7de8000 r-xs 00128000 68:03 42012257                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/ant.jar
2aaab7de8000-2aaab7df3000 r-xs 0005f000 68:03 42012258                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/xstream-1.3.1.jar
2aaab7df3000-2aaab7df6000 r-xs 0000f000 68:03 42012259                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/commons-discovery-20030211.213356.jar
2aaab7df6000-2aaab7e1a000 r-xs 00180000 68:03 42012260                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/bouncycastle1.45.jar
2aaab7e1a000-2aaab7e1c000 r-xs 00007000 68:03 42012261                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7e1c000-2aaab7e28000 r-xs 0008b000 68:03 42012262                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/ehcache-core-2.1.0.jar
2aaab7e28000-2aaab7e2d000 r-xs 00014000 68:03 42012263                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
2aaab7e2d000-2aaab7e30000 r-xs 00022000 68:03 42012265                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/jamon-2.7.jar
2aaab7e30000-2aaab7e36000 r-xs 0004f000 68:03 42012266                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.osgi.core-4.3.0.jar
2aaab7e36000-2aaab7e3b000 r-xs 0002a000 68:03 42012267                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/commons-beanutils.jar
2aaab7e3b000-2aaab7e48000 r-xs 000bd000 68:03 42012268                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/jpos.1.9.4.1.jar
2aaab7e48000-2aaab7e49000 r-xs 00000000 68:03 42012269                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab7e49000-2aaab7e4f000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304362                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
2aaab7e4f000-2aaab7f4e000 ---p 00006000 68:03 42304362                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
2aaab7f4e000-2aaab7f50000 rwxp 00005000 68:03 42304362                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
2aaab7f50000-2aaab7f63000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304368                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
2aaab7f63000-2aaab8064000 ---p 00013000 68:03 42304368                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
2aaab8064000-2aaab8067000 rwxp 00014000 68:03 42304368                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
2aaab8067000-2aaab8368000 rwxp 2aaab8067000 00:00 0 
2aaab8368000-2aaab836a000 r-xs 00002000 68:03 42012271                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
2aaab836a000-2aaab836d000 r-xs 00023000 68:03 42012272                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/jdom-1.0.jar
2aaab836d000-2aaab8371000 r-xs 00023000 68:03 42012274                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.wsdl4j-1.6.1_1.jar
2aaab8371000-2aaab8377000 r-xs 0002d000 68:03 42012275                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab8377000-2aaab8389000 r-xs 00092000 68:03 42012276                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
2aaab8389000-2aaab838b000 r-xs 00006000 68:03 42012277                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
2aaab838b000-2aaab838d000 r-xs 00002000 68:03 42012278                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.jar
2aaab838d000-2aaab8391000 r-xs 0001f000 68:03 42012279                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar
2aaab8391000-2aaab8392000 r-xs 00002000 68:03 42012280                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/spring-batch-test-2.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar
2aaab8392000-2aaab8395000 r-xs 00014000 68:03 42012281                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/logback-access-0.9.28.jar
2aaab8395000-2aaab8396000 r-xs 0000e000 68:03 42012283                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/jline-0.9.91.jar
2aaab8396000-2aaab8398000 r-xs 0000b000 68:03 42012284                   /home/sipa/release/switch/lib/spring-batch-test-2.0.4.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
2aaab8398000-2aaab839b000 r-xs 0001b000 68:03 42075948                   /home/sipa/release/switch/bin/wrapper.jar
2aaab839b000-2aaab839c000 r-xs 00003000 68:03 42075941                   /home/sipa/release/switch/bin/run.jar
2aaab839c000-2aaab839e000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42696759                   /home/sipa/release/switch/bin/linux-x86-64/libwrapper.so
2aaab839e000-2aaab849e000 ---p 00002000 68:03 42696759                   /home/sipa/release/switch/bin/linux-x86-64/libwrapper.so
2aaab849e000-2aaab849f000 rwxp 00002000 68:03 42696759                   /home/sipa/release/switch/bin/linux-x86-64/libwrapper.so
2aaab849f000-2aaab84a7000 r-xs 00115000 68:03 42304347                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/resources.jar
2aaab84a7000-2aaab84ae000 r-xs 00094000 68:03 42304603                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/jsse.jar
2aaab84ae000-2aaab84b1000 r-xs 00013000 68:03 42305089                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/jce.jar
2aaab84b1000-2aaab84c0000 r-xs 00667000 68:03 42304359                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/charsets.jar
2aaab84d5000-2aaab84d9000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 50135063                   /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2aaab84d9000-2aaab86d8000 ---p 00004000 68:03 50135063                   /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2aaab86d8000-2aaab86d9000 r-xp 00003000 68:03 50135063                   /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2aaab86d9000-2aaab86da000 rwxp 00004000 68:03 50135063                   /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2aaab86da000-2aaab86dd000 ---p 2aaab86da000 00:00 0 
2aaab86dd000-2aaab87db000 rwxp 2aaab86dd000 00:00 0 
2aaab87db000-2aaab87de000 ---p 2aaab87db000 00:00 0 
2aaab87de000-2aaab88dc000 rwxp 2aaab87de000 00:00 0 
2aaab88dc000-2aaab88df000 ---p 2aaab88dc000 00:00 0 
2aaab88df000-2aaab89dd000 rwxp 2aaab88df000 00:00 0 
2aaab89dd000-2aaab89e0000 ---p 2aaab89dd000 00:00 0 


2aab27f82000-2aab28080000 rwxp 2aab27f82000 00:00 0 
2b1c19827000-2b1c19828000 rwxp 2b1c19827000 00:00 0 
2b1c1983d000-2b1c1983e000 rwxp 2b1c1983d000 00:00 0 
2b1c1983e000-2b1c19845000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304372                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
2b1c19845000-2b1c19946000 ---p 00007000 68:03 42304372                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
2b1c19946000-2b1c19948000 rwxp 00008000 68:03 42304372                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
2b1c19948000-2b1c1994a000 rwxp 2b1c19948000 00:00 0 
2b1c1994a000-2b1c1a264000 r-xp 00000000 68:03 42304396                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b1c1a264000-2b1c1a366000 ---p 0091a000 68:03 42304396                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b1c1a366000-2b1c1a51b000 rwxp 0091c000 68:03 42304396                   /home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b1c1a51b000-2b1c1a555000 rwxp 2b1c1a51b000 00:00 0 
7fff56dff000-7fff56e14000 rwxp 7ffffffea000 00:00 0                      [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dhq.autoinventory.name=switch -Dsipa.home=. -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.50.6.30 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.ext.dirs=../../sipa.lib:../../lib -Dcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.NullManagementCoordinator -javaagent:../../lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar -Xmx4096m -Djava.library.path=../../bin/linux-x86-64/ -Dwrapper.key=yr0DRcFwt29AgfTr -Dwrapper.port=32002 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=24652 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=10 
java_command: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp com.tosan.sipa.Program ../.. file:../../path.props file:../../app.spax,file:../../mbeanAdaptor.spax
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11gr2/JRE:/u01/app/oracle/product/11gr2/jlib:/u01/app/oracle/product/11gr2/rdbms/jlib:/u01/app/oracle/product/11gr2/network/jlib
PATH=/home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11gr2/bin:/root/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64/server:/home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/lib/amd64:/home/sipa/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/../lib/amd64:/u01/app/oracle/product/11gr2/lib:/u01/app/oracle/product/11gr2/ctx/lib
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x85f800], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x85f800], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x70e300], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x70e300], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x70e300], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x70e300], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x711110], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libwrapper.so+0x1410], sa_mask[0]=0x00000001, sa_flags=0x10000000
SIGINT: [libwrapper.so+0x13b0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000002, sa_flags=0x10000000
SIGTERM: [libwrapper.so+0x13e0], sa_mask[0]=0x00004000, sa_flags=0x10000000
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x710d10], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)

uname:Linux 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Mon Mar 29 22:10:29 EDT 2010 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 364543, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:1.47 1.72 1.41

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:     45317860 kB
MemFree:        364600 kB
Buffers:        628608 kB
Cached:       38777112 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:       24403576 kB
Inactive:     18694084 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:     45317860 kB
LowFree:        364600 kB
SwapTotal:     8289532 kB
SwapFree:      8289228 kB
Dirty:           25024 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     3691516 kB
Mapped:          54504 kB
Slab:          1694348 kB
PageTables:      55628 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:  30948460 kB
Committed_AS: 12141468 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:    270388 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359467867 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB


CPU:total 24 (6 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 44 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 44
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 2665.983
cache size  : 12288 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc arat pni monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5331.96
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 44
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 2665.983
cache size  : 12288 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 12
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 32
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc ida nonstop_tsc arat pni monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5331.83
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: [8]





Memory: 4k page, physical 45317860k(364584k free), swap 8289532k(8289228k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.1-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_26-b03), built on May  4 2011 01:13:47 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

time: Wed Sep 17 09:31:08 2014
elapsed time: 190 seconds
```

(I remove some similar logs for `stackoverflow` limits, I can send complete log for anyone by email)

Anyone can guide me?

**EDIT:**
My development environment same as production environment : `JRE 1.6` , `SUSE` os.
different between two environment is : production environment is `64 bit` and development environment is `32 bit`

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide information about the difference between prod env and dev env (linux distribution, JVM implementation, etc) :)

Comment: @Nizil At end of log files define production environment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.1-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_26-b03), built on May  4 2011 01:13:47 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux) and development environment is same config but 32 bit systems and os

Comment: If the JVM crashes,  there is a bug in the JVM or in native code.

Comment: The problem is definitely related to bitness: I see that an array reference has been cut to 32 bits and thus became invalid. Could you post the complete crash dump to pastebin.com?

Comment: @apangin please send a email address for send crash dump?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the package: com.tosan.sipa.security.jceadapter.JCESMAdapter

You can take a look at Oracle "Troubleshooting Guide for Java SE 6 with HotSpot VM":
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/crashes-137240.html